# few-day old dell shuts down randomly, wondering if this is a software or hardware issue

Tags: boot, dell, shutdown, restart

I recently got a dell 15 5000 (7th gen i5, touchscreen) laptop and almost immediately switched to Ubuntu 16.04, and twice now ( 4 days later) I have shut the lid and left, and come back and opened it and found my laptop shut of instead of suspending, and when I try to boot it, it will start for about half a second (lights will turn on) but before the screen comes on, it will shut back off and fail to boot. after attempting multiple times, it will eventually start like normal and give no indication that it failed. wondering if this is just a fault of the hardware and I should send it back and rebuy (I love the laptop other than that) or whether its a issue with lunux? thanks so much and sorry if this isn't the best location for this question

Comment: when you say similar, do you mean your issue also involved issues with booting? i'm not so much worried about the random shut-downs (i just have to remember to actually save my work) as I am about that
-thanks

Comment: I've put my suggestions into an answer.

Comment: I'd recommend two things... install `intel-microcode` to make sure that your CPU's are up to the latest revision... in `terminal`... `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`. Reboot, go back into `terminal` and `dmesg|grep microcode` to see it in action. 2nd... I'd either update to 16.10, or boot to the 16.10 Ubuntu Live DVD and see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with suspend, especially with brand new laptops, and linux because graphics cards are not supported. If you still have windows installed, check that it works ok with suspend, etc to rule out hardware issues. In linux, if you install the appropriate graphics drivers that may enable suspend to work correctly. If you still experience issues after this and Patrick's suggestions, I would lean towards hardware then.

The caveat with what I say above is only valid if what you mention about 'instead of suspending, and when I try to boot it, it will start for about half a second (lights will turn on) but before the screen comes on, it will shut back off and fail to boot' is you coming back to the laptop and merely opening the lid and waiting for it to start up. If you mean it is completely off and you press the power button to bring it back up and it does that, then I would lean more towards hardware being the issue.

HTH! - Kyle

Comment: i do mean the latter (in that when I open it and suspend is not working properly it seems to be fully off and it takes pressing the power button a few times to get it to boot. If you think it's a hardware issue / if it seems to be one, do you think my best bet would be to send the machine back and get a new one?

Comment: If the Windows partition has the same behavior, I would exchange it. If the Windows partition was erased, you will need to do a restore before exchanging it anyways, or they may say that you tampered with it by installing another os, and thus void your warranty. If Windows shows the same symptoms, it is definitely a hardware issue.

Comment: All graphics cards on the market produced by mainstream producers are supported by Ubuntu. I think this is an ACPI issue with his Kaby Lake CPU.

Comment: It could be an acpi issue. I disagree that all graphics cards are supported, however.

Comment: mhhhhhm what's an acpi exactly?

Comment: ACPI is a standard that operating systems use to talk to a motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a hardware issue, but seems rather like a software issue. As you have a very new Kaby Lake CPU I heavily advise the following:

- Update your kernel to 4.8, or upgrade to 16.10. The 4.8 kernel has much better support for Kaby Lake CPUs.

If this doesn't work, try adding these kernel parameters:

- `acpi_sleep=nonvs`
- `intel_pstate=disable`
- `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`

By pressing "e" at startup, and adding them after the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

Example:

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"`

Note: adding these at boot is temporary. Take half an hour or so to mix and match these parameters. *If one combo works, do the following:*

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Add your kernel parameters as you did above. Then, run the command

`sudo update-grub`.

If absolutely none of these suggestions work, then please file a bug in [Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

You may also want to test this behavior with a LiveCD.

Comment: If none of the suggestions work, it's important to exchange the machine for a new one before the return period ends.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I explicitly stated that this definitely does not seem like a hardware issue, but one with Ubuntu. Exchanging devices won't help.

Comment: Right, and you could be wrong about that.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Sure, I could. But the issue is reproducible, at least on my machine.

Comment: If they have the same cpu and are able to reproduce the issue, I'd say its an ubuntu issue and not a hardware issue. No harm in trying out their suggestions. Please let us know the results, I'd be very interested to know if it is a cpu issue.

Comment: for me the issue doesn't happen each time, when you say it's reproducible do you have a way to forcibly trigger it for testing? @PatrickNegus
thanks all for all the help

Comment: @aridelTufo I simply delete the kernel parameters at boot. Exact same issues. I heavily advise booting a ***16.10*** LiveCD and seeing if you can reproduce these issues.